# Display Scaling, or how to make the display not go past the edges of my screen

Tags: 16.04, display

I have 16.04 installed on my computer using the onboard video driver of the i5-3570 CPU.  When I run "lspci | grep VGA" it returns "00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)".
The system will eventually be a headless Media server, but I want the display working "right" while I get the system configured and tested. currently, the server is connected via an HDMI cable to a POS Emerson 32" LCD TV with no remote control.

The display is bigger than the screen by just a little bit and I'm hoping that there is a way to position/scale/move/set the edges so that I can see everything.
I've looked at the displays setting in the system, and at the Appearance setting but haven't found anything. I've Googled some, but haven't been able to find the answer there either.

Is there a way to adjust the edges of the display so they fit inside the physical screen?

Comment: Sounds like you have to calibrate the screen from within the menu of your LCD TV, refer to the manual of your LCD TV how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't adjust from the TV itself.  I have tried all the menu options, and no longer have the remote that came with the TV.  The TV is not even listed on the Emerson site anymore.  I'm really hoping to be able to adjust this through software.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for my issue after more digging.
Using code `xrandr --output HDMI1 --transform 1.05,0,-35,0,1.05,-19,0,0,1` has gotten me almost exactly where I can see everything.
I found the answer here at this URL: [Overscanning picture problem using HDMI with Intel Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508358/overscanning-picture-problem-using-hdmi-with-intel-graphics)

Comment: This worked but is causing glitch in mouse cursor on my primary monitor. It starts to blink periodically.