# Underscan on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: display, 17.10, hdmi, xrandr

I'm trying to use a TV as a screen but it overscans everything (with no option to disable it).

I tried using the suggestions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508358/overscanning-picture-problem-using-hdmi-with-intel-graphics) to underscan but they wouldn't work; xrandr doesn't recognize "underscan" as a command and using the transform suggestion doesn't resize anything, only moves it around so that while the top and left sides are aligned properly, the bottom and right sides are even more cut off.

**Ubuntu 17.10**, Intel HD Graphics 630, connected with HDMI. Xorg or Wayland, I'll take either.

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:** Here's what I'm doing to change the resolution:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --transform 1.05,0,-40,0,1.05,-30,0,0,1
cvt 1880 1050
# 1880x1050 59.94 Hz (CVT) hsync: 65.28 kHz; pclk: 164.50 MHz 
Modeline "1880x1050_60.00"  164.50  1880 2000 2200 2520  1050 1053 1063 1089 -hsync +vsync

sudo xrandr --newmode "1880x1050_60.00"  164.50  1880 2000 2200 2520  1050 1053 1063 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

When I then go to select the new resolution, my screen goes black and then resets to 1920x1080 after 20 seconds.

I've also tried `sudo xrandr --newmode "1880x1050_59.94"  164.50  1880 2000 2200 2520  1050 1053 1063 1089 -hsync +vsync` out of curiosity but same thing happens.

Comment: What's the make and model of the TV? Sometimes the overscan is buried deep in settings menus and someone with the same TV might know.

Comment: Hitachi something or other. I already contacted Hitachi support and was told the option doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure how you would do it but after transforming to get left & top to line up appropriately you need to change your screen size from 1920x1080 to something less such as 1900x1060 if you added 20 to both left & top. I almost did this the other day until I found the 1:1 pixel setting buried deep inside the Sony TV Android menus.

Comment: I tried adding a custom resolution but my screen just goes black when I apply it and then resets to the normal 1920x1080. I don't know how to change that.

Comment: You should update your question with the mode line or cvt commands you used and the results you got.

Comment: OK, I've added that!